# Passing a date to a queryset based on a button click in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have RoastManifest View that querys date_scheduled (field from my RoastManifest model) and returns distinct values.  I pass that queryset to a template and loop over the values and present them as buttons on the HTML file.  I am able to click any button and pass the corresponding date into the URL,((localhost/schedule/2019-06-20) when I click on the June, 20 2019 button) thus redirecting me to my RoastManifestDetailView.  Now I want to be able to filter my RoastManifestDetailView based only on the date passed to the URL (or which date button was clicked).

I have tried `RoastManifest.obejects.filter(date_scheduled__date=date.today())`just to see if I could return anything schedule for today but I keep getting Fielderrors (Unsupported lookup 'date' for DateField or join on the field not permitted.).  Please note I know that is not the exact queryset for me.  I wish to pass in a variable into the queryset.

This is the model: 
(NOTE: roast_order is in there only to allow for use of adminsortable2 library)

```
class RoastManifest(models.Model):
    def batch_number_incrementer():
        current_max = RoastManifest.objects.order_by('-batch_number').first()
        if current_max:
            return current_max.batch_number + 1
        else:
            return 8000000
    batch_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True,
                                       default=batch_number_incrementer,
                                       )
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="products",
                                on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date_scheduled = models.DateField()
    roaster_profile = models.ForeignKey(RoasterProfile,
                                        on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    roast_order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('roast_order',)
```

This is how I pull the individual days scheduled:

```
class RoastManifestListView(ListView):
    model = RoastManifest
    template_name = 'schedule/scheduled_days.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['days'] = RoastManifest.objects.order_by('date_scheduled').values('date_scheduled').distinct()
        return context
```

This is the view I am having trouble with:

```
class RoastManifestDetailView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'schedule/roastmanifest_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["roasts"] = RoastManifest.objects.get(date_scheduled__date=date.today())
        return context
```

I want to be able to click on a day (button) and pass that date into the query, thus returning everything scheduled for that specific day.

With the above RoastManifestDetailView I am currently getting a FieldError

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the models above, I believe the correct query would be: `RoastManifest.obejects.filter(date_scheduled=date.today())`... your query was looking for a field called `date` on the `scheduled_date` field, but there is no such property.

When you are ready to query based on the clicked button, there are several ways to do it but the easiest (and "correct-ish-est" way) would be to pass the date in the URL as a query param: `<button href="<URL to route>?date={item.scheduled_date}" ...>` or something like that (you will probably have to play with date formats a bit to in your settings but you want something like `2019-06-21`), and in your view you can get the value of that param using: `date = request.GET.get('date', None)` which will return the string value of the date query param which you can then use in queries and things (again possibly after some conversion) or `None` if there is no parameter with that name.